# Can I use express.js uploaded file names as an IDs?

Tags: node.js, express

Once a file is uploaded using express.js it gets a new name (I guess a hash or something) So is that hash unique? Can I use it as a file ID, say in a dababase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the file names are *mostly* going to be unique, but there is always a chance of a collision. [Here](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/blob/master/lib/incoming_form.js#L516) is the source of the hash generator from [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/):

```
IncomingForm.prototype._uploadPath = function(filename) {
  var name = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    name += Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16);
  }

  if (this.keepExtensions) {
    var ext = path.extname(filename);
    ext     = ext.replace(/(\.[a-z0-9]+).*/, '$1');

    name += ext;
  }

  return path.join(this.uploadDir, name);
};
```

Since `Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16)` will give you a hexadecimal value, you have a **16^32** chance of a collision. That is **1** in **340282366920938463463374607431768211456**, which is the same chance of a collision as a MD5 hash (**2^128**).

So yes, you could use the hash in a database, but it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

So how are you receiving the file?

I assume you're using a form for the upload?
If so, the hash you are seeing is probably just the temporary file name and you still have to write the uploaded file to the disk (or a database of course).

The whole procedure is really well explained in this article: http://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads

So internally express' bodyparser uses node-formidable which chooses the temp folder based on this expression: `process.env.TMP || process.env.TMPDIR || process.env.TEMP || '/tmp' || process.cwd();`

Just to be sure you should use one of the hash algorithms provided by the crypto node core module.

Generate the hash like in this example (fileData should be the file):

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var uniqueID = (crypto.createHash('md5').update(fileData, 'utf8').digest("hex")).toString();
```

Comment: Yes I'm using a form, and I do move and rename my files. But my question is about the name/hash of the uploaded files before I move and rename them. Are they unique? can I use that hashes as IDs instead of generating IDs myself. A use case is: to create a unique url for every uploaded file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `shortId.generate()` to generate a unique ID.

```
var shortId = require('shortid');   
var uniqueFileName = shortId.generate();

fs.rename(file.path, cfg.data + '/uploads/' + uniqueFileName, function(err){
    user.profileImage = uniqueFileName;

    user.save(function(err) {
        if ( err ) return res.json(400, err);

        res.json(200, { profileImage: user.profileImage });
    });
});
```